# How good does the weather have to be for a rocket launch?

Tags: launch, rockets, launch-sequence, weather

I'm watching a launch sit on hold because the sky is overcast. The announced hold reason was "thick cloud cover, anvil cloud". So they have a checklist. What is on that checklist? How do they assess that checklist - for instance, how far away does an anvil cloud have to be for them to consider conditions a go? In this launch, they are aiming for a gap in the conditions that they are calculating to arrive at a particular time, and adjusting the countdown accordingly. They must be looking at the radar and judging when the cloud cover and surrounding clouds will fall within acceptable parameters.

Comment: The Russians launch through way worse weather than the Americans do.  design choices early on.

Comment: Related: [Why are rocket launches so sensitive to weather?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/4967/49) and [Can a rocket be launched while it rains?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/3863/49)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in the related questions TildalWave posted in a comment it really depends on the rocket (because I have it [here](http://www.universetoday.com/90939/soyuz-launches-to-station-amid-swirling-snowy-spectacular/)'s an article about a Soyuz launch in a snowstorm) and what the range they're launching from supports.

Considering you asked on April 27th you were probably watching the SpaceX TurkmenÄlem52E/MonacoSat (Thales) launch.  For that specific launch I found this screenshot of the launch commit criteria:
[image: TurkmenÄlem52E launch commit criteria]
That's sourced from [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/33xqcj/rspacex_turkmen%C3%A4lem52emonacosat_thales_official/cqqgbz3) reddit post.  I don't know where he got the screenshot but it's an interesting post all around.

Note that the checklist breaks it down into separate groups for the range and the Falcon 9, [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_commit_criteria#Falcon_9) provides more detail but doesn't give any such separation.  On the other hand, the wikipedia page is sourced from [this NASA document](http://www.nasa.gov/pdf/649911main_051612_falcon9_weather_criteria.pdf) which only includes the Liftoff Winds rule from the Falcon 9 specific criteria and otherwise appears to match the range criteria.  Also, if I remember correctly the first stage landing criteria was a nice to have, not a requirement to launch (maybe why it's marked as N/A).

To quote wikipedia (since it's better formatted for copying text out of than the NASA pdf), the Falcon 9 cannot be launched under the following conditions:

- sustained wind at the 162 feet (49 m) foot level of the launch pad in excess of 30 knots (56 km/h; 35 mph)
- upper-level conditions containing wind shear[quantify] that could lead to control problems for the launch vehicle.
- launch through a cloud layer greater than 4,500 feet (1,400 m) thick that extends into freezing temperatures
- launch within 19 kilometres (10 nmi) of cumulus clouds with tops that extend into freezing temperatures,
- within 19 kilometres (10 nmi) of the edge of a thunderstorm that is producing lightning within 30 minutes after the last lightning is observed.
- within 19 kilometres (10 nmi) of an attached thunderstorm anvil cloud
- within 9.3 kilometres (5 nmi) of disturbed weather clouds that extend into freezing temperatures
- within 5.6 kilometres (3 nmi) of a thunderstorm debris cloud,
- through cumulus clouds formed as the result of or directly attached to a smoke plume,

The following should delay launch:

- delay launch for 15 minutes if field mill instrument readings within 9.3 kilometres (5 nmi) of the launch pad exceed +/- 1,500 volts per meter, or +/- 1,000 volts per meter
- delay launch for 30 minutes after lightning is observed within 10 nautical miles (19 km; 12 mi) of the launch pad or the flight path

This is a hard question to answer generally (without just resorting to "it depends), but if you're interested in other rockets the wikipedia link above also includes criteria for Atlas V and the Space Shuttle.

Comment: Heck, it never occurred to me that there would be a Wikipedia page  - classic case of needing to know what to search for. You've added a bunch of other good stuff too, great answer.